# Ruby: require_relative not able to load file

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have written below code which uses a .rb file from another directory but on executing this code I receive an error:

```
require_relative '../page/site_element.rb'
    #define new browser
browser=SiteElement.new("http://demo.mahara.org")

    #input user name
browser.login_username.send_keys('Student1')

    #input password
browser.login_password.send_keys('Testing1')

    #click on submit button
browser.submit_button.click

    #wait until the Logout link displays, timeout in 10 seconds
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
wait.until {browser.logout_link }

    #if logout link is displayed
isLogoutLinkDisplayed=browser.logout_link.displayed?

puts isLogoutLinkDisplayed
browser.close_browser
```

Below is the error I am receiving:

```
D:/Ruby - POC/test/login_test.rb:1:in `require_relative': cannot load such file
-- D:/Ruby - POC/page/site_element.rb (LoadError)
        from D:/Ruby - POC/test/login_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from -e:1:in `load'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

[image]

Comment: Does this file exist `POC/page/site_element.rb`?

Comment: Yes. it exists in poc/page.

Comment: copy paste the path of the file after listing it.

Comment: Please find tree structure of directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `site_element.rb` locates in `D:/Ruby - POC/pages`, not `D:/Ruby - POC/page`.

```
require_relative '../pages/site_element' # note the 's'
```

Comment: I got it.. Such a silly mistake.. My bad. Sorry for wasting time.!!!